# How to configure polkit with KDE?

Tags: permissions, gentoo, kde4, polkit

My system is Gentoo amd64, KDE 4.11, and lightDM. I updated my system recently, and found out my user account can't shutdown from KDE. The function is disappeared. I looked for a long time, and I think it is a permission issue. I checked some blogs/wikis talking about **polkit** configuration. But none works for me.

So bascially, my question is, how to let a non-root user to have administrator permission in KDE with **polkit**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up `ConsoleKit` and migrated to `systemd`. Solves all my pain :)

Answer (score 0):

Your user belongs to the group power? It's necesary to have power management controls.

if not, run this like root : `gpasswd -a user group`

Comment: but I don't have the *power* group  on my system at all...